# Password protect a CSS nav?

Tags: css, tabs, passwords

So, I created a body on pastebin for the elements of my page, using it's source so I can do a simple page made out of CSS. My only issue is that I want to be able to password protect one tab in particular. Whatever it takes, whatever the effort that is needed, I'll do it.

```
<span id="navi" onclick="document.getElementById('start').innerHTML=document.getElementById('a').innerHTML;">STORE</span>
<span id="navi" onclick="document.getElementById('start').innerHTML=document.getElementById('b').innerHTML;">SALES</span>
<span id="navi" onclick="document.getElementById('start').innerHTML=document.getElementById('c').innerHTML;">VIP</span>
<span id="navi" onclick="document.getElementById('start').innerHTML=document.getElementById('d').innerHTML;">INGREDIENTS</span>
```

This is how I have made my tabs in CSS. The page I want to password protect is "VIP" with the id "c"

```
<div id="c" style="display:none;">
<center><h1>VIP AREA</h1></center>
```

How can I password protect this page so that someone will have to enter a password to view the VIP tab?

Answer (score 1):

What server-side framework are you using if any? (e.g. ASP.NET MVC)

"This is how I have made my tabs in CSS" - I think you mean HTML.

You wouldn't want to do any client-side authentication or authorization since anyone can read your JavaScript.  Typically the user will already be authenticated and you should have some kind of authorisation (e.g. roles) to decide whether to render the VIP tab or not.

If you always want to display the VIP tab you could do an AJAX call when tab is clicked and depending if the user is authorised or not would determine if HTML for the VIP tab is downloaded from the server or not.

Comment: Yep, I'm pretty sure this is the only way to do it.

Comment: Actually, this is just part of the code. I just wanted to show the basics of what I wanted done and where. The rest of my code is CSS (the elements etc) but the code I have shown is HTML, yeah. What you said has severely confused me actually! So I have no idea what to do and how I'd do what you suggested. I guess I'm pretty much screwed.

Comment: @NinaMaxelle - if you're unsure of what I was talking about let me know which parts you don't understand and I can try explain further.